# what's the meaning of "around"

Tags: meaning

> My aspiration for Dartmouth is to let it soar with its strengths,
>   which are many; become the best it can possibly be around those things
>   which it already does so well.
>
> -Jim Yong Kim, World Bank President-

In the above sentence , what does a word 'around' means and how does it work in this sentence?

I thought it is a preposition with the meaning "together with" or "along with".

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a variation of preposition definition 1.1 in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/around):

> (Of something abstract) having (the thing mentioned) as a focal point: *our entire culture is built around those loyalties*

This definition seems to be a metaphoric generalization of the more concrete senses related to surroundings of places.

Answer (score 1):

*Around* was not the best choice for the sample sentence. The more accurate replacement would be as follows:

> ...become the best it can possibly be ***in*** those things which it already does so well.

The general expression is "to be the best *in* something," not "*around* something," or even "*together with* something."